# Not able to deploy crowdsale

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts

when i am doing truffle migrate.i am able to deploy my crowdsale contract but my token contract is getting deployed but not the crowdsale contract.

```
var Sportist = artifacts.require("./Sportist.sol");
var SportistCrowdsale = artifacts.require("./SportistCrowdsale.sol");


module.exports = async function (deployer) {
    let rate = 1;
    let wallet = "0x300c7b7198a772C2154e4f2a47C0d89407a95A8A";
    let token;
    let openingTime = Math.floor((new Date()).getTime()/1000);
    let closingTime = openingTime + 1 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    let cap = 500000;
    let goal = 50000;
    let tokenWallet = "0x300c7b7198a772C2154e4f2a47C0d89407a95A8A";

let a  = await deployer.deploy(Sportist, "Sportist", "S", 6, 2000000000)
 console.log("asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd");
token = await Sportist.deployed().then(instance=>instance.address)



await deployer.deploy(SportistCrowdsale,
    rate, wallet, token,
    openingTime, closingTime,
    cap,
    goal,
    tokenWallet)

    const crowdsale = await DappTokenCrowdsale.deployed();


console.log("after deployement ");
```

};

in the console it is showing that

```
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 2_deploy.js
  Replacing Sportist...
  ... 0x211c7f7e0678bacec29a7d8032ae8949faca2cc381586b8b541f5faf3804c1f9
  Sportist: 0x2fb7fa517002ca3a7af45deea0479f287d5089fb
Saving successful migration to network...
asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd
  ... 0x760538642ffd049748b5bf3ff5624b0065e6b0e3bbbb1aaf99ad341de2bc99f1
  Deploying SportistCrowdsale...
Saving artifacts...
```

and the crowdsale contract is

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "./crowdsale/distribution/RefundableCrowdsale.sol";
import "./crowdsale/distribution/PostDeliveryCrowdsale.sol";
import "./crowdsale/validation/CappedCrowdsale.sol";
import "./crowdsale/emission/AllowanceCrowdsale.sol";
import "./crowdsale/emission/StagedCrowsale.sol";

contract SportistCrowdsale is RefundableCrowdsale, CappedCrowdsale, PostDeliveryCrowdsale, AllowanceCrowdsale, StagedCrowsale {
    constructor(
        uint256 rate, address wallet, IERC20 token,
        uint256 openingTime, uint256 closingTime,
        uint cap,
        uint256 goal,
        address tokenWallet) 
        Crowdsale(rate, wallet, token)
        TimedCrowdsale(openingTime, closingTime)
        CappedCrowdsale(cap)
        RefundableCrowdsale(goal)
        AllowanceCrowdsale(tokenWallet)
        StagedCrowsale()
    public {}

    function() external payable {
        buyTokens(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

Comment: can we see the crowdsale contract code?

Comment: i have edited now check it .

Comment: Contract looks great! Contracts are from [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts/crowdsale) I would like to know few more things from you. Are you deploying to main network or are you doing something like 'truffle migrate --network rinkeby' ? Also, does execution end without errors or does it stay forever in the state of 'Saving artifacts...'?

Comment: i am deploying it on ganache.

Comment: I found other people with the same error. It can be a random/casual error. Check [this](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-migrate/issues/14) and [this](https://github.com/rhlsthrm/truffle-hdwallet-provider-privkey/issues/3)  my advice to you is to change network ID on ganache or try 'migrate --reset --network different_networkID' . Eventually just go on ganache and click on settings button and change network ID to something like '5782'. Let me know if that worked

Comment: not working bro

Comment: found the answer await is not supported in earlier version .its there only in beta version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use async function in new truffle beta version.so i updating the truffle version you can easily use await. i updated to the new beta version of truffle